# Memcached Fault-Tolerance and failover property

Tags: memcached, failover, fault-tolerance

As mentioned on this page: [Memcached for PHP and failover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372031/memcached-for-php-and-failover),

I am trying to test the failover of Memcached.

Basically, I want to ensure that if one of the server is marked dead, subsequent sets and gets should get re-distributed to the servers that are left over.

Someone mentioned on this page that OPT_AUTO_EJECT_HOSTS is one option to achieve this.

However, It seems that Memcached::OPT_AUTO_EJECT_HOSTS is depreciated as decribed on this page:http://hoborglabs.com/en/blog/2013/memcached-php

I tried using OPT_REMOVE_FAILED_SERVERS option also. But this makes no difference.

I also tried OPT_SERVER_FAILURE_LIMIT, setting it to 1.

Benchmark/request generator in my case, is BRUTIS.

https://code.google.com/p/brutis/

I'm using libmemcached-1.0.16, memcached-1.4.15, and the php version of memcached is 2.1.0.

What should I do to make the failover and automatic rebalancing to work.

I am trying different combinations of these options also. But, it does not work.

There is a related question:
[Brutis and memcached FailOver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783257/brutis-and-memcached-failover)

But no answer yet :(

If anyone has any idea about this, please share your views.

Thanks in advance,
Amit